# How to debug the following Jenkins error?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I just recently created a new Jenkins pipeline which is reading from Jenkinsfile script in the repository.
I created a branch and then committed this script to the repo. Now I am trying to build this branch on jenkins but I get the following error and I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I basically copied the Jenkinsfile from an existing repo which I can build successfully. This is my first build for this project but its not working. please advice. when it says 'skipped due to earlier failure' what does it mean and how to identify this failure?

```
Commit message: "Project Foundation"
Cleaning workspace
 > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
Resetting working tree
 > git reset --hard # timeout=10
 > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
[Pipeline] sh
+ git describe --tags
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
Stage "Build" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
Stage "Test" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Publish Dev)
Stage "Publish Dev" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 128
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your Jenkinsfile (or part of it)? It would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repository seems to not have tags to be described.

Jenkins reaches to run `sh` shell script `git describe --tags` (see the plus sign `+` in the beginning of the line, which means it was run), but it fails fails with exit code 128, shown in the end of console output:

> ERROR: script returned exit code 128

Apparently, `git describe` seems to exit with that code if there is nothing to describe (tags in your case).

To continue from here you can remove the line, or add ignore the error by adding `|| true` to the command:

```
sh "git describe --tags || true"
```